# Where is the jeweler in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

How do you get the jeweler in Diablo 3? Is he acquired automatically as a quest later in the game or is he a random encounter?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Jewler is located in ACT II, you first acquire the Jeweler during Act II, Quest 7, Blood and Sand.

Answer (score 11):

You will first encounter the [Jeweler](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/) during the Act II quest "Blood and Sand.  In the sewers, you will find a Talking Barrel.  Inside the barrel, you will find Covetous Shen.  After freeing him, you will go on a short quest to recover an item the Crucible.  After recovering the Crucible, Covetous Shen will set up in town similar to Haedrig.

Answer (score 1):

*You unlock the jeweler like you unlock the blacksmith, by doing the quest line.*

The Jeweler is unlocked in the ACT II after the 7th quest of that ACT ("Blood and Sand").[¹](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149615403#3)

Comment: It is possible to get gems *before* unlocking the Jeweler.

Comment: Really? I read somewhere that was not, so I add it in the edit. Thanks for point that.

Comment: I got a gem before i unlocked the Jeweler.

Comment: I got quite a few gems before unlocking the jeweler. They're just random drops in the game. They're all white gems though, so if you're not looking for them, you might not notice them, if you're not picking up white items.

Answer (score -1):

Covetous Shen is in the Waterlogged Passage.