# How do I complete Everybody Loves Shen if Shen isn't unlocked until Act II?

Tags: diablo-iii

While perusing the achievements list, I found one called "Everybody Loves Shen", which requires listening to all of Shen the Jeweler's conversations. This includes a number of conversations that the achievement marks as Act I:

- The Restless Dead
- Tell Me About Yourself
- Deckard Cain
- Jewels
- King Leoric
- The Fallen Star
- Grieving
- The Stranger
- The Journey Ahead

Thinking he'd eventually show up, I played through Act I only to get to the end without him showing up. Looking online, it turns out [Shen doesn't appear until Act II](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67019/where-is-the-jeweler-in-diablo-3). Fair enough, but how does one complete conversations he only has in Act I?

Is the achievement text wrong? Or is it the case that once you unlock Shen in Act II, he magically appears in Act I forevermore? If so, does he appear when switching quests in normal, or do you have to complete the game once before he shows up in Act I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unlocking Shen permanently unlocks him for all later difficulties and all future characters, so if you decided to try a higher difficulty with your character you can have those conversations with him or you can create a new character on normal and have the conversations with him there. (I have done so myself)

Answer (score 1):

Once you unlock Shen in Normal difficulty, he will follow you also on the other difficulties. So basically all you have to do is start a new game in Nightmare mode and he'll be there waiting to talk to you.

Answer (score 1):

Unlocking Shen in Act II on normal difficulty unlocks him for every difficulty and Act (especially Act I) so you can talk to him in Act I after unlocking him in Act II (you have to either redo all quests on normal difficulty or simply get the conversations later on).

The same is true for Haedrig Eamon.